# Can I add long press event for alert controller

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, swift4

Can I add long press event for alert controller in action sheet mode.

if user long pressed want show one more pop in normal alert mode.

```
   let actionSheet = UIAlertController.init(title: "Favourites", message: nil, preferredStyle: .actionSheet)

    if(favLocations.count != 0){

        for i in 0...(favLocations.count - 1){
            actionSheet.addAction(UIAlertAction.init(title: favLocations[i].villageName, style: UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler: { (action) in

                self.tbLocation.text = self.favLocations[i].villageName


                }))
        }
    }

    actionSheet.addAction(UIAlertAction.init(title: "Choose Locations", style: UIAlertActionStyle.destructive, handler: { (action) in
        self.showAllLocationAvailable()
    }))
    actionSheet.addAction(UIAlertAction.init(title: "Cancel", style: UIAlertActionStyle.cancel, handler: { (action) in
    }))

    self.present(actionSheet, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that it is not possible in current iOS SDK. You may want to implement your own `AlertController` or look for some open source libraries.

Comment: Any Idea  about open source library which is releated to my question